# Why does Rudy's shadow walk away from him in Misfits opening?

Tags: misfits

Why does Rudy's shadow walk away from him in Misfits opening?

Answer (score 3):

Rudy's shadow represents [Rudy Too](http://e4-misfits.wikia.com/wiki/Rudy_Too), representing his power of [Emotional Duplication](http://e4-misfits.wikia.com/wiki/Emotional_Duplication).